# Nginx as reverse proxy of .Net Core 5 gRPC server send 502 error

Tags: nginx, grpc, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm doing test with Nginx and .Net Core 5 gRPC with the simplest cases.

1.- Using Visual Studio 16.10 I have created a server using the ASP.NET Core gRPC Service template, only making some changes on:

```
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options => {
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001, listenOptions => {
                        listenOptions.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http1;
                    });
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5002, listenOptions => {
                        listenOptions.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http2;
                    });
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5003, listenOptions => {
                        listenOptions.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                    });
                });
```

2.- Running on VS and using BloomRPC the server response at localhost:5002, that's ok since I'm not using TLS and forcing http/2 on port 5002.

3.- Plublishing the project targeting Linux X-64 and deploying on Oracle Linux 8.4, it run ok and can be reached through the LAN with the ip:port as 192.168.1.1:5002.

4.- Configurating Nginx version 1.14.1 (overwriting /etc/nginx/nginx.conf) with:

```
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format grpc_json escape=json '{"timestamp":"$time_iso8601","client":"$remote_addr",'
                                     '"uri":"$uri","http-status":$status,'
                                     '"grpc-status":$grpc_status,"upstream":"$upstream_addr"'
                                     '"rx-bytes":$request_length,"tx-bytes":$bytes_sent}';

    map $upstream_trailer_grpc_status $grpc_status {
        default $upstream_trailer_grpc_status;
        ''      $sent_http_grpc_status;
    }

    server {
        listen  50051 http2;
        
        access_log   /var/log/nginx/grpc_log.json grpc_json;

        location / {
            grpc_pass grpc://localhost:5003;
        }
    }
}
```

Always got a 502 response from Nginx, even trying with: grpc_pass grpc://localhost:5001 (http1 only) and grpc_pass grpc://localhost:5003 (http1 and http2).

What's wrong with the Nginx configuration?

Comment: have you tried the 3 ports? i don't see you try 5002 in grpc_pass

Comment: Hi Lei Yang, Yes I tried on each port: 5001, 5002 and 5003, I left the 5003 in the code sample since it is open to http1 and http2. Thanks for notice the lack of clarity.

Comment: 502 means bad gateway. i think you can check some nginx logs to see if there's any errors.

Comment: The log show: client: 192.168.1.1250, uri:/greet.Greeter/SayHello, http-status:502, grpc_status:, upstream:127.0.0.1:5003.

Comment: not enough log. i have no clue now. are you familiar with nginx configs? if not, i suggest setup a http 1 reverse proxy first, after success, try grpc

Comment: I used this guide: https://docs.oracle.com/en/learn/oracle-linux-nginx/  to install and run tests. Nginx is working right. I think the problem is on the location /, there must include a route. Before I posted this question I read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62644659/how-to-enable-nginx-reverse-proxy-to-work-with-grpc-in-net-core, but still I can't figure out how to route. I have tried with /greet.Greeter/ but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: i read the [nginx doc](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-10-grpc/), but still cannot find issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works!!

1.- Don't trust on /etc/yum.repos.d/oracle-linux-ol8.repo it is stuck on versión 1.14 of Nginx and at time of writing version 1.20.1 is available; instead create a repo file following the instuctions: https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#RHEL-CentOS

```
sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
[nginx-stable]
name=nginx stable repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/rhel/$releasever/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
module_hotfixes=true

sudo yum install yum-utils
sudo yum install nginx
```

2.- The minimum nginx.conf must include logs

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    log_format grpc_json escape=json '{"timestamp":"$time_iso8601","client":"$remote_addr",'
                                      '"uri":"$uri","http-status":$status,'
                                      '"grpc-status":$grpc_status,"upstream":"$upstream_addr"'
                                      '"rx-bytes":$request_length,"tx-bytes":$bytes_sent}';

    map $upstream_trailer_grpc_status $grpc_status {
        default $upstream_trailer_grpc_status; # We normally expect to receive grpc-status as a trailer
        ''      $sent_http_grpc_status;        # Else use the header, regardless of who generated it
    }

    server {
        listen 50051 http2;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/grpc_log.json grpc_json;
        location / {
            grpc_pass grpc://localhost:5000;
        }
    }
}
```

3.- Now Nginx support HTTP/2 on the upstream side, so we can use only http2 on Kestrel

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options => {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000, listenOptions => {
                    listenOptions.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http2;
                });
            });
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

4.- Inspecting the /var/log/nginx/error.log it report (13 Permission denied), thanks to https://www.devopszones.com/2020/07/13-permission-denied-while-connecting.html?m=1. I realized the source trouble is SELinux permissions. CentOs, RHEL and Oracle Linux enforce an strict SELinux settings, depending of the distro there is a solution on: https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/
in my case with the following instructions works:

```
sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 50051 
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Good Luck and enjoy ASPNet Core gRPC with Nginx !!